# Finding ratio of external division in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, vectors

Given a $\triangle ABC$ and $P$ dividing $AB$ internally in the ratio $2:3$ $Q$ dividing $AC$ internally in the ratio $1:2$ , with $PQ$ produced and $BC$ produced intersecting in $R$ , to find the ratio in which $R$ divides $BC$.

Just by drawing a rough sketch, it is clear that $\frac {BR}{RC}<1$.
[image]

I tried solving this using vectors as follows.

Given $\vec a , \vec b , \vec c , \vec p , \vec q , \vec r$ being the position vectors of $A,B,C,P,Q,R$ respectively,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{p} & = & \frac{3\vec{a}+2\vec{b}}{5}\\
\therefore\vec{b} & = & \frac{5\vec{p}-3\vec{a}}{2}\\
\vec{q} & = & \frac{2\vec{a}+\vec{c}}{3}\\
\therefore\vec{c} & = & 3\vec{q}-2\vec{a}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Let }\vec{r} & = & \frac{k\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{k+1}\\
\therefore\vec{r} & = & \frac{k\left(\frac{5\vec{p}-3\vec{a}}{2}\right)+\left(3\vec{q}-2\vec{a}\right)}{k+1}\\
 & = & \frac{5k\vec{p}+6\vec{q}-\left(3k+4\right)\vec{a}}{2\left(k+1\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}

That's where I'm stuck. Is there a way to express $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ in terms of $\vec a$ ?

Is there another way to solve this that would be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $RB=kz$.

Construct $QS$ parallel to $AB$ and note that $\triangle CQS \sim \triangle CAB$ and that $\triangle RPB \sim \triangle RQS$. See the following figure.

[image]

Using similarity you get: $QS=\frac{10}{3}u$ and $k=9$.

I think you can finish by yourself now.